# Determining what Url the user originally entered to visit a web page after redirection

Tags: asp.net

Currently, I'm just using clientside Javascript (`location.href`), but I am wondering if there is a way in Asp.Net to figure out the URL the user originally entered (assume I did not change it myself via 301), or at least to track it in a simple and reliable manner.  As I am using my own implementation of URL rewriting via the global.asax (e.g. `Context.RewritePath`), this is not an easy task, particularly since I don't want to touch it too much.

**Example**

```
Global.asax:
    public override void Init()
    {
        base.Init();
        this.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(Global_BeginRequest);
    }

    void Global_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (VARIOUSCONDITIONS) Context.RewritePath("SOMEURL");
    }

SomePage.aspx.cs

    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Request.RawUrl is equal to "SOMEURL", as 
        //are other properties that store the URL.
    }
```

Comment: Can you please give us an example...

Comment: @Aristos: I added a basic example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I am misunderstanding your question, but if you are trying to capture the page the user first hits on your website, cant you capture this in the session_start event of global.asax? Then store in sessionstate or database for future use?

Comment: That sounds like it will work.  Will test when I get a chance.

Comment: +1 For a nice idea, though this won't work without a bit of tweaking, because the session_start event is also triggered for pages other than the one the user requests (e.g. axd files).